# Filetransform task escapes newline during Azure pipeline task

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I inserted the following variable in the library
`mymultilinevar\ncontaininganewline`

When I file transform the following string is inserted
`mymultilinevar\\ncontaininganewline`

How can I prevent this? 
Regards,

Comment: Hi Morrowyn Did you get chance to try out below solution. How did it go? Please let me know if there is any question.

Comment: Heya, I havent tried it yet. But it's still on my list to try it out as it looks very promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below steps to fix this.

1, Use a delimiter(eg, `;`) instead of `\n` to divide the new line in your multiline variable.

For example. Define your variable(eg.`myVariable` in below example) as `mymultilinevar;containinganewline`

2, Add a script task before File Transform task to replace `;` with `%0A` (which is the hexadecimal value of `\n`).

And update your variable(`myVariable`) with the replaced value. See below example scripts in powershell task:

```
$muline = "$(myVariable)" -replace ";", "%0A"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVariable]$($muline)"
```

See document [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) about statement `##vso[task.setvariable]`

3, Then run File Transfom task, the variable should be replaced with `mymultilinevar\ncontaininganewline`

[image]